# How to Automate On-Premises to Azure SQL Database Data Export?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have 5 SQL Servers where there is an average of 200 Databases on each of them, how can I go about exporting all of these databases to azure and create the SQL Databases with the same name in azure as well.

This Can be done using azure automation account feature the DSC Configurations?

Can someone tell me or point me in the right direction for this??

Comment: oh wait, my bad, thought you need to move azure sql to azure sql, for this task you would use t-sql or powershell as well, however I dont have a code at hand

Comment: This needs to be done without login to the On-Premise VM.

Comment: also this can be a 1 time job

Answer (score 0):

[Azure Database Migration Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/database-migration/) can really help you in this case. Locate the service on Azure portal and create a "Migration Service" for each database server. It will ask you for subscription, resource group, VNET, location and pricing tier. For the pricing tier choose Basic if you intend to migrate small and medium tier sizes. In your case, use "General Purpose". Take advantage that SKU choices of database migration service are currently in preview.

Once you have created the project you can click on it and the following Migration Wizard will appear. Provide the name of the on-premise database server on step #1. On Step #2 select all 200 databases on the server, On Step #3 select the target. On Step #4 you will have to provide a SMB network share that Migration service will use to take backups of the on-premises database.

[image]

Once you finished the wizard you can follow the progress on the migration project as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Hi Alberto, I am getting an error when I try to connect the ADMS to my on prem sql server, what can be the reason behind this??

Comment: You need to create a VNET with access to your on-premises resources (source) and with access to the target SQL Azure Servers. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quick-create-portal

Comment: This is the documentation tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quick-create-portal

Comment: I have the vnet that has access to the source and target servers, opened thE ports as well but I still cant connect my onprem server to DMS

Comment: I have not had those issues. It may be worthy creating a support ticket so they can help you troubleshoot connection to your database servers.